# Display house numbers on the street corners

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a street map (MuliLineString geom and house numbers min and max, left and right).

I would like to show this numbers on the street corners. I use GeoServer.

If I use the TextSymbolizer with LinePlacement the label is in the middle of the line.
If I use it with Geometry (startPoint and endPoint function) I can't move it in parallel. (All the labels are at the same point.)

Have you any idea?

Thanks

Comment: In which software you are displaying the house numbers ?  ex. Open layer etc.

Comment: can you add a picture of what happens when you use start/end Point - as that is the way I was going to suggest

Comment: Here is my map: http://i49.tinypic.com/qw48.png
The first rule is for red street (startPoint < endPoint), the second is for green (endPoint > startPoint)